# Can't update boot security on new Macbook Pro

Tags: macbook-pro, security, external-disk, startup

I am trying to boot from an external device and it is asking for an administrator password. The machine is new and didn't have a password so I created an admin password and it still won't allow me to update the security settings for startup disks.

I have cloned my old MacBook (2016 MacBook Pro 13") and I am trying to restore on to my new MacBook Pro (2018)

Comment: is it Mojave ? ...

Answer (score 1):

I was able to move past this by creating another account (called admin) then switching between my account and the admin account. Once I did this I was able to open the dialog box and move forward.